# Design - Web API 2 - Query mechanism

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

I need to do some POC using Web API 2. That web api should be able to help users to filtering fields and get the data back to that fields only instead of complete Entity.

The requirement as follows.

End Points:

GET /A ( default: Acol1,Acol2,Acol3 ) - Get all default properties from     Entity/Table A

GET /A?fields=Acol1 - Get only one column Acol1 from entity A

GET /A?fields=Acol1,B(Bcol1,Bcol2) - Get a column from A Entity and 2 columns from B Entity

GET /A?fields=Acol1,AComputed - Get a column from Entity A and computed column (user does not if it part of the entity or computed column)

GET /A?fields=B(BCol1) - Get only one column from Entity B

Please let me know your best thoughts and ideas to do it in a better way. Much appreciated your ideas and suggestions.

Thanks
BNet

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, I will look into it.

Comment: This does not work as per my requirement. so we need lot of customization from fields pattern in query string and resolving the contract. So what I did was Extended the MediatypeFormatter and Serialization.DefaultContractResolver and that helped us to achieve the project requirement. Thanks for your quick reply CodeCaster